# Write array to file in a readable format

Tags: php, arrays

I have integrations with Logistic partners. I post to them data in a array format. I want to store this array into a file as a log. How do i store this array into file in a readable format. i tried but it just prints as array in file. It is a multidimensional array.

Comment: Use json_encode(). _JSON Format_

Comment: What does your array look like and what do you want it to read like?

Comment: Its multidimensional array. If i get some error, i just have to open the file and see what i posted to LSP

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: @Manwal, you should create that as an answer and add the option about JSON_PRETTY_PRINT.

Answer (score 1):

You can try JSON,

To save it,
     file_put_contents("my_file.json", json_encode($array));

To get it back,
     $array = json_decode(file_get_contents("my_file.json"));

Comment: If you want the file pretty, add in a JSON_PRETTY_PRINT in the json_encode call

Answer (score 0):

check whether this helps you...

```
 $people = array (
            "jay" => array (
                            "last_name" => "greenspan",
                            "age" => 32
                            ),
            "john" => array (
                            "last_name" => "doe",
                            "age" => 52
                            )
            );


$myfile = fopen("newfile_testing.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

while(list($person, $person_array) = each($people))
{
    $txt1 = "\n\nWhat I know about ".$person."is :\n\n";
    fwrite($myfile, $txt1);

    while(list($person_attribute, $value) = each($person_array))
    {
        $txt2 = "\t".$person_attribute."\t=\t".$value."\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt2);
    }

}
```

**Ouput in the text file:**

```
What I know about jayis :

last_name   =   greenspan
age =   32


What I know about johnis :

last_name   =   doe
age =   52
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
      $commodity = array (
            array (
                     "item" => "woofer",
                     "price" => 70
                  ),
            array (
                     "item" => "beer",
                     "price" => 13
                  )
            );
$data = json_encode($commodity);
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp,$data);
?>
```

This might work. If you give the data as json, then you / clients can access it easily, like a simple API, where you request something and get json/xml data

Answer (score -2):

Depending on the structure here (and how many dimensions), the easiest way is a series of for loops - 1 for each dimension. May even want to consider recursion, if the number of dimensions is variable ... not the nicest of code, but will work.

By using count (to get the size of the array), you can control your loop and not read off the end of the array.

Utilising tabs/spaces/new lines to separate each element makes it easier to read. As does writing out the index of that array.